# Insert the count from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i create this query for the count , now i want to insert the count from the table('orders') in table('users') column 'frequented' where orders.user_id=users.id

```
 $frequented = DB::table('orders') 
                   ->join('users','orders.user_id','users.id')
                   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_id'))
                   ->groupBy('user_id') ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$frequented = DB::table('users')->select([
    'users.*',
    'orders_count' => DB::table('orders')->selectRaw('COUNT(*)')
        ->whereColumn('user_id', 'users.id')
])->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

note : note : i don't tested this code please test it
i hope can help you